# How to reuse perf charts in OpsCenter from datastax?

Tags: cassandra

Key idea of my question is that I want to use my predefined list of charts from OpsCenter for different keyspaces. So I need to figure out it there any possibility to create list of performance plots for new keyspace without OpsCenter UI?

I found some similar question about performance graphs migration from one center to another(http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/export-performance-graph-setup-from-one-opscenter-to-another), and there was no possibility for community 1.0.3 version

Answer (score 0):

There's not currently a way to do this in OpsCenter, but we're in the process of redesigning how those dashboards work and adding functionality to make managing graphs much easier.  This use case specifically isn't something we've discussed, but I'm make sure it's included in future conversations.